# Python pyplot text with square root

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, text, symbols

I'm trying to annotate my pyplot with the following:
[image]

I am able to get the square root of a number, and I am able to get the h-squared, but when I put them together I get a

```
ValueError: cannot switch from automatic field numbering to manual field specification
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
plt.plot(x, y)
t=97.35713828629935
plt.text(1,5,r'{:3.1f}% greater than $$\sqrt{0.5*$h^2$}$$'.format(t))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the second pair of `{}` confuses `.format`. Use double `{{}}` to escape them.

`plt.text(1,5,r'{:3.1f}% greater than $\sqrt{{0.5 * h^2}}$'.format(t))`